# MySQL query to update field in a table based on value of other field in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

I've been trying to figure out the correct query for the following issue and I cannot seem to find the solution myself.

I'm running a WooCommerce store which stores a bunch of values as 'meta_key' in a MySQL table with the value stored in the 'meta_value' column.

What I want to do is update the 'meta_value' of 'meta_key' 'pisol_exact_lot_arrival_date' to a specific date based on an SKU search on the 'meta_value' '_sku' column.

I wrote the below query but I'm getting an error when I execute this: "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause".

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = '31/03/2022'
WHERE `post_id` =
    (SELECT post_id
     FROM wp_postmeta
     WHERE meta_value = 'MM083ZM/A')
  AND `meta_key` = 'pisol_exact_lot_arrival_date'
```

[This is what my table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhTaj.png)

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why isn't this simply: `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '31/03/2022' WHERE meta_key = 'pisol_exact_lot_arrival_date' AND meta_value = 'MM083ZM/A'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a temporary table so that mysql doesn't give that erorr any more.

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = '31/03/2022'
WHERE `post_id` =
    (SELECT post_id
     FROM (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta) wpp
     WHERE meta_value = 'MM083ZM/A')
  AND `meta_key` = 'pisol_exact_lot_arrival_date'
```

Comment: Thank you @nbk! This was the solution, thank you very much! I have now discovered that the 'meta_key' 'pisol_exact_lot_arrival_date' only exists in the database when entered in the WooCommerce frontend. How can I modify the query that it should create this 'meta_key' if it doesn't exist yet and update it if it already exists?

Comment: that will only go with dynamic sql, or you write a procedure and use the flow control there, to make an insert if it doesn't exist or a update like bouve